# Как сделать двигающуюся платформу - Unity?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

[image: платформа][image: чанки]

Всем привет, я уже день пытаюсь реализовать двигающуюся платформу в юнити. В придачу мне надо, чтобы при столкновении с другими объектами платформа останавливалась на 5 секунд. У меня на уровне их очень много и следовательно я не хочу писать их передвижение через стартовые и конечные точки.

Вместо этого я придумал другой алгоритм их передвижения:

1. Если мы соприкоснулись с любым объектом(OnCollisionEnter), то пускаем луч вперед и назад из пустых объектов. (изображен передний пустой объект на картинке. задний симетричен)
2. Если задний луч попал мы к текущей позиции прибавляем скорость
3. Если передний луч попал мы от текущей позиции отнимаем скорость

Вот как я это реализовал в коде:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class BluePlane : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private Transform ForwardHit;
        [SerializeField] private Transform BackwardHit;
    
        private IEnumerator MoveObjectForward()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    
            transform.localPosition += transform.right * 0.01f;
        }
    
        private IEnumerator MoveObjectBackward()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    
            transform.localPosition -= transform.right * 0.01f;
        }
    
        private void Shoot()
        {
            RaycastHit forwardHit;
            RaycastHit backwardHit;
    
            if (Physics.Raycast(ForwardHit.transform.position, ForwardHit.transform.forward, out forwardHit, 0.1f))
            {
                StartCoroutine(MoveObjectBackward());
            }
    
            if (Physics.Raycast(BackwardHit.transform.position, BackwardHit.transform.forward * -1, out backwardHit, 0.1f))
            {
                StartCoroutine(MoveObjectForward());
            }
        }
    
        private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
        {
            Shoot();
        }
    }
```

Но проблема в том, что при Instantiate() чанков метод OnCollisionEnter не работает ._.

Ооу, кажется я понял OnCollisionEnter срабатывает тогда, когда **движущейся** объект соприкасается. А ведь платформы у меня не двигаются, а Instantiate() это я полагаю не движение. И поэтому мой скрипт не работает. Но как тогда решить эту задачу?